# Deploying windows application to .Net never installed systems

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I wanted to deploy my windows application coded using c# (visual studio 2010).
I am expecting it to install & run successfully on windows xp , 7 or higher version.
How do i give .Net framework along with my setup file, when the client machine doesnt have .net installed ?

Or is there any better way to selectively enable client machine with required .Net features which were specifically used by my application.

Comment: Are you using an installation package builder? If so, which one, and I can give you more specific instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/). It's very easy to use :)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your install bundler. At my workplace, we use InnoSetup, so we just add a dependencies section to our build script.